# Failed to load Json File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to access a json file via javascript but i get no output whatsoever. 
The file order is following:

```
index.html
/dataset/dataset.json
/scripts/script.js
```

Here the code:

```
$.getJSON("dataset/dataset.json", function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

And here the json file:

```
{"data":[
    {
        "letter":"A",
        "blocks":{
            "1":"0",
            "2":"0"
        }
    }
]}
```

The console outputs nothing, not even an error.

**Solved:**
The error was in the json file. I posted a shorter version of it here. I forgot to put a } on line 171 of the original file. My bad.

Comment: You're actually not handling the error., just the success callback.

Comment: Is this code in the _script.js_ file? If so, the path to the `JSON` file is wrong.

Comment: @MelanciaUK How can I handle the error? Yes the code is in the script.js file.

Comment: Chain this: `.fail(function() { console.log("error"); });`

Comment: Documentation: [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Now it outputs error.

Comment: Check the documentation to know how to get the error that's occurring. I still bet is the file path.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: _“Is this code in the script.js file? If so, the path to the JSON file is wrong”_ – not if that script is embedded into `/index.html`

Comment: in the call to getJSON, could you change the path to "/dataset/dataset.json"? As it was commented, it might be a problem with the path, since they way you wrote it's looks for the file inside /scripts/dataset/dataset.json

Comment: It is embedded into index.html and as much as I know, it is not the file path which is wrong.

Comment: @FreeCandies I tried that and then I get the 404 error.

Comment: Did you manage to get the error that's occurring? You don't need to keep guessing... `.fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,error) { var err = textStatus + ", " + error; console.log("Request Failed: " + err); });`

Comment: @MelanciaUK I added that, now i get the error:
Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: So there's something wrong with your `JSON`. Curiously, it parses on JSONLint, so it should be OK.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I found the error! The json file is more than 2k lines long so i did post a shorted version of it. The error was on line 171 where I forgot to put a }. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad you spotted the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong. Use an absolute path like `getJSON('/dataset/dataset.json')`. What is the `url` you are serving this script file? Can you visit `url/dataset/dataset.json` to make sure you serve the json file correctly.